# Count the number of companies per country in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following 2 excel sheets in the same workbook:

companies:

```
    A          B
1 COMPANY   COUNTRY
2 Apple     USA
3 Microsoft USA
4 Samsung   Taiwan
5 Philips   Netherlands
6 Tulip     Netherlands
```

countries:

```
    A             B
1 COUNTRY      NUM_COMP
2 USA          2*
3 Taiwan       1*
4 Netherlands  2*
```

In sheet `countries` column `B` I need the number of companies per country. I have now counted them by hand, but I need a formula for cells `B2` to `B4` to do this automagically, since the actual sheet is much, much longer than this example.

Can anyone help me? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://superuser.com/questions/189762/excel-how-to-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-range

Comment: Please see below. I tried implementing it, but can't get it to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function 'Countif' should be helpfull :)

> =COUNTIF(B:B;B2)

cheers
Sky

Comment: I tried `=COUNTIF(companies!B2:B2265;B2)` but it returns zero in every case?

Comment: Please try to copy entire column B from sheet "companies", on data tab there is something like "remove duplicate". Then use this countif.

Comment: You can also try to put coutif function on companies sheets just to check if it's works

Comment: If I put `=COUNTIF(companies!B2:B6;B2)` in `A7` on `companies` sheet, it works. It return `2` (2 USA companies) as expected. Also, there are no duplicate entries in my sheet. I don't see where it goes wrong...editting into `=COUNTIF(companies!B2:B2265;countries!B2)` also doesn't help. Now I'm confused. Perhaps you have another idea?

Comment: Given your description should it be: `=COUNTIF(companies!B$2:B$2265;A2)` - that should work if you don't have duplicates......otherwise try the formula I suggested

Comment: My bad - I used `B2` instead of `A2` as the criteria. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the number of different companies per country try this formula in B2

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(companies!B$2:B$2265=A2,MATCH(companies!A$2:A$2265,companies!A$2:A$2265,0)),ROW(companies!A$2:A$2265)-ROW(companies!A$2)+1),1))`

That's an "array formula" which needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula in the formula bar.

Now copy formula down column

Comment: I get "the formula you typed contains an error". When clicking OK, it highlights `A2,MATCH`?

Comment: Sorry, I see you are using ; instead of , (it depends on region) - replace all commas , in my formula with semi-colons ; - but this formula is more than you need if you don't have duplicates - you can just stick with the simple COUNTIF